# Cypress - "cannot read property 'text' of null" when using cy.log in a .should Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I'm a Cypress newbie, still trying to figure out the Cypress/JS behavior.
The purpose of my script below is to extract the value of a column and store the value as variable.
However, I found #Method B throws error which I cannot figure out why this happens. Thanks in advance for any directions or explanations given.

#### #Method A - works fine

```
cy.get(`[aria-colindex="4"]`).should(($column) => {
    VPC_UID = $column.text()
}).then( () => {
    cy.log("VPC_UID:"+VPC_UID)
})
```

#### #Method B - throws error (see below screenshot)

```
cy.get(`[aria-colindex="4"]`).should(($column) => {
    VPC_UID = $column.text()
    cy.log("VPC_UID:"+VPC_UID)
})
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not to sure why it goes to chain method `should` if cypress can't find that DOM. Can you show full the test case anyway?

Comment: in method B - i believe promises are not getting resolved

Comment: @tmhao2005  this is already to whole test case ... XD

Comment: @GreenLake4964 Have you found the cause/soluion?